# What can be done to remind candidates to slim down their resumes?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

A lot of my candidates via so careers still submit 6-10 page resumes. 
Unfortunately no one is going to read this many pages.

People are listing out every single technology they have heard of.  They put in stuff like Ruby, asp.net, sqlserver, jQuery, js, java, c++, c, c#, css, html5, wpf...insert any tag here...Then you call them and they don't even know how to call a web service.

I know we are not a resume writing service, but can a check be done such that when someone tries to upload a document larger then 1-2 pages we warn them?  We don't have to stop them, just warn them that employers generally don't like very long resumes and they are generally thrown out if they are this long.

Most recent 3 candidates with the average page size of 6-7 pages.  I am getting to the point where I don't even want to look at these resumes, these are novels not resumes.
This is a disservice to them as I hate to pass people up that really maybe good employees.

Or even better, what if when they tried to submit their resume we told them the careers / jobs resume will format their resume for them and it will look much nicer than what they are uploading and recommend them to use careers/jobs resume instead of uploading the word / pdf document.

Comment: I get it was intentional, but I think your post is coming off too ranty.  You may want to tone it down and focus on the issue.

Comment: For the issue itself.  I'd say do it simple.  Either a standard warning when the resume exceeds `x` pages for anyone, or scale length warning by experience so a very junior level people would get a warning after 2 pages and more experienced people would get longer resumes before warnings would appear

Comment: @psubsee2003 - after reading so many you become ranty sorry.  I don't care if you have more experience that shouldn't mean write me a book..max 1-2 pages irregardless of any of that.  No one needs to have 6 page resumes...even if you went to Mars, you'd list it on your first page as an accomplishment and you'd be hired period.  You don't tuck it away on page 6 and hope for the best.

Comment: So after 3 long resumes you're already annoyed? Why don't just go over the first 2 pages, which generally include the most important parts of a resume. Then if you consider interviewing, mention that a long resume is generally well received,

Comment: Doesn't that also depend on culture a bit? I'm all in for reducing the noise but if that only open up positions for me in your company I might miss other offers. Specially if you dismiss my resume because you reckon the commute would be to tiresome for me...

Comment: @JustDoIt - So you'd think, a few of these have the most relevant information on the last page.

Comment: @rene - You really don't need to list every darn thing you do.  I mean do you really possibly list every single thing you do at the workplace as a bullet point.  This is what I'm talking about...i mean if you're developing code you don't need to tell me that.  Tell me something you've taken ownership of or lead.  Don't tell me you simply declare variables, look at source code, fix bugs, etc.  This is what your daily routines are not what you should be most proud of.

Comment: Seems to me if they start listing off a never ending list of alphabet soup that's a great indicator that they royally suck.  NEXT!

Comment: @rene - Everything I've read on writing resumes says that you keep it to one page when you're starting out and don't go past two ever. Anything above that would be for something like a CV when applying to be a teacher at a university and you list all of your publications. There seems to be very little variation on the expectations for resumes in the United States and those all appear to be for specific types of positions.

Comment: @BSMP I don't plan to find a job in the States ...

Comment: Maybe there should be a link to the [resume](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume) tag over at The Workplace. Or maybe just a resume help page that lists the norms for each country?

Comment: @rene - Wait, does the Careers site not allow you to have more than one resume to use?

Comment: @BSMP - Careers lets you upload a resume when you apply.  So you could upload as many as you want but it takes the latest.  So in reality its one...

Comment: The downvoters are all those who have more than 2 pages on their resumes - boo to you you're part of the problem!

Comment: @BSMP probably but then this useful warning should be tailored for the country the job is in you're applying to?

Comment: Not sure why this gets closed for that reason. Although written as a rant it still tries to discuss if a warning is something to consider so candidates using Jobs/Careers have a better chance in being invited/hired. Remember: We try to make the internet a better place!

Comment: @rene - Looks like any discussion on how this should work will need a new feature request.

Comment: @BSMP I agree with you but I wanted some discussion first. Obviously some people don't understand the issue. Vote to reopen

Comment: @BSMP sure, this question tries to work out first how that feature request should be formulated which isn't a bad idea, given the current comments...

Comment: I'm a downvoter, and my resume is exactly 2 pages long @JonH , your post although good, it comes off more like a rant. That's the reason of my downvote.

Comment: Just do it so edit it to fit your politically correct needs.  Make America great again.

Comment: Voting to close because this is not an appropriate venue for discussion of the employer side of careers (especially rants). Same should provide a separate place for that.

Comment: Andrew uhmm yes it is.  All jobs related info goes on meta so.

Comment: I'm an upvoter, although I hate rants and my resume is 1 page long. Letting inexperienced folks write inferior resumes without even warning them about basics is a disservice to them

Comment: I'll try to edit out the rants...thanks gnat

Comment: @AndrewMedico There have been plenty of questions about the employer side of careers/jobs asked here. I don't know why you'd think it's off-topic. It's true that they *also* solicit feedback from business customers in other ways, but that doesn't mean it's unsuitable here.

Comment: I got rid of the ranting please feel free to further edit my post if need be.  Please understand my concern from an employee vs employer perspective.

Comment: You made America great again @JonH

Comment: Just Do It - America's always been great vote for JonH.

Comment: This would be a really great feature... I wish I could upvote myself.  We need some traction here.  I despise long resumes, unless you're pursuing a job that requires a lot of publications like academic role.  However, this is rarely if ever going to be used for academic purposes.  Most jobs are for companies looking to hire software developers.  We want to become the de facto standard for people to find a job here.  We need to help employees out and by helping them we help the employers.  I was recently in a management meeting the other day discussing interviewing.  1 manager said when he...

Comment: ...gets long resumes he tosses them out.  We need to stop that!

Comment: So...this is in regards to the people that attach multi-page PDFs, right?

Comment: Makota it's not just PDFs.  It's anyone who uploads a resume in any format, this can come in word as well...technology or format type doesn't matter here.

Comment: @JonH By the time someone is ready to upload their resume, it's already too late. Nobody is going to see that dialog and decide to do hours of more work to trim down the resume. The majority will just click Yes/Continue/Forward/Attach/JustFDoIt and move on with their lives. If you don't like reading long resumes, don't.

Comment: Cypher so negative... Think what you want I'm advocating and pushing for change.  I deal with your type of attitude daily.  I won't accept it!

Comment: @JonH I agree with your point (though last time I checked mine was 3 pages ;) ) I don't think that Cypher's was being at all negative in his comment though, it is pretty rare that I'll go through my CV and edit it for a particular job, it needs to really catch my attention to do so. With that warning I would very likely shrug and get on with my life in some way! - I think your frustration with the topic is doing your point a disservice though, you do come across as being very ranty to the point of rudeness. (in my opinion at least)

Comment: Michael that's your opinion.  I'm speaking on behalf of those who have to hire.  Three pages is long too!

Comment: Know what else is getting pretty long and painful to read? This comment thread, that's what :) I think this is okay to be here, because while it's mostly a problem statement, it's _so_ close to a feature request that I think it would be a waste to close it. There's enough here for someone on the Careers / Employer facing side of things to answer.

Comment: "insert any tag here" <- every question I read on main (meta curiously normally is on the slim side)

Comment: Actually we don't know for sure if you're speaking in behalf of all of the ones on the hiring side, I wouldn't generalize it.

Comment: Just an FYI I just got two more resumes both over six pages long.  This feature is needed ASAP.

Comment: Recent cover letter was 8 pages long, see here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320696/limit-introduce-yourself-aka-cover-letter-when-applicant-applies?noredirect=1#comment331553_320696 why are these basic features not being [status-completed] already?