# Limit "Introduce Yourself" (aka Cover Letter) when applicant applies

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Please limit the "Introduce yourself" textbox when someone applies for a job.  A few candidates simply copy cut and paste their resumes into this box.  Please limit this box to say 200 words?

[image]

I just copied and pasted a recent one I got into word and it was the following:

[image]

It also spanned 8 pages long.  This is way too much information for someone to "introduce" themselves.

Comment: But... the more I say in my personal statement and the more acronyms I cram into my experience the better I am, right?

Comment: @Will - Well you are the exception...besides you are too good for us anyhow!

Comment: @JonH "It also spanned 8 pages long." is way to long for a CV as well ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill - You're talking to JonH here, I've mentioned this here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320298/what-can-be-done-to-remind-candidates-to-slim-down-their-resumes

Comment: Why would you throw away information which allows you to so easily identify applicants who can't communicate quickly and clearly?

Comment: Ben it's a cover letter not a story.

Comment: Ben besides most people can identify what you speak of by reading the first couple of sentences.

Comment: They are already limiting you `Tell WSM International why you're a good fit for their needs`

Comment: That's not a technical limit at all.

Comment: Would've gained more upvotes by using a free hand circle...

Comment: @TJ: [Here's the image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyf3Q.png)  with freehand circles. Counting on you; should get upvotes :)

Comment: @DavidPostill in my part of the world, 8 pages is considered too short! urg...

Comment: I'm with @BenVoigt on this one, if I'm selecting candidates and they can't give me a proper short cover letter, their chances just dropped in half. Their resume have to sparkle to overrule my first impression.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu - But than it isn't fair because some of these candidates just cut and pasted a resume in this field.  Making it force only a limit of the number of words would make them think twice.

Comment: I personally believe this is a bad idea. I took more interest in candidates who gave more details in their cover letter allowing me to see personality and actual interest in our job posts. When I came across copy/pasted resumes with no regard for our posting, I just declined them and moved on. This is a blanket fix for lazy candidates who are quickly applying to a lot of places and will have a negative affect on some candidates and employers.

Comment: @JonH why would you hire someone that naturally doesn't think twice? How can we, as software developers, be what we're suppose to be (software developers) without naturally thinking at least twice?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu - To me it is obvious what a cover letter is.  To others, think different types of people, they may not know.

Comment: As a reference point, I had a candidate that included a 2,107 word cover letter that was very personalized. We went on to interview this candidate. I can't say we would have if not for some of the content within the cover letter.

Comment: @JonH I see your point. I disagree with the solution of limiting it just to help people understand what a cover letter is, but I see your point.

Comment: @CarrieKendall, are you wanting to employ people that are good at writing cover letters, or people that are good at writing code.....

Comment: As well as being a good developer, I am looking for someone who can  communicate clearly, @IanRingrose. That may be different for you or the next employer but, limiting a cover letter to such a low character count  limits insight into applicants.

Comment: @CarrieKendall - 200 words is good enough for a cover letter.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Using limits to force a behavior you prefer is a bad solution. Have you considered adding something to your job posts that leads the applicants to limit their cover letters to 200 characters or less?

Comment: @CarrieKendall - No, and I wouldn't consider that.  The job posts have nothing to do with the applicant filling out a cover letter.  You getting that much information about a candidate is just too much info.  I personally think thats added noise.  If you cannot tell if the candidate fits your team in 200 words than I think you may have bigger problems to solve.

Comment: http://idealistcareers.org/how-long-should-your-cover-letter-be/

Comment: Well, luckily for me, you're not making this decision :) I'm not going to get into a prolonged meta rant about how you or I should hire. I don't agree and have downvoted for that reason. Happy hiring!

Comment: Not sure what you imply but to each his own.  Rant?  Downvoted?  Boy are you angry.  Apparently there are 26 others who agree with me...if not more.

Answer (score 13):

I think this should be limited to something like 200 words.   Otherwise some candidate will feel they must write a long text, while other candidates only write one or two lines.

HR then comes along, and decides they like the candidates that put in a lot of effort, or the candidates that kept it short.   Unpredictable, so making the process too dependent on lack.

Comment: I agree with this 100%.  I'm not sure why I initially stated 1000 chars, that is simply way too much, I was being generous.

Comment: @JonH, 1000 chars is about 200 words, people are just better at thinking in words.

Comment: True maybe you are right, I'll edit my original post back in terms of words...Programmers aren't people you know :-p.

Comment: 200 words is only 400 bytes or 100 dwords.  For the 64-bit among us (and who doesn't want to appear 64-bit literate), that only allows communicating 50 pointers.  Seems bit short.

Answer (score 13):

A soft-limit might be a better approach. If the cover letter is more than X number of words (maybe an option that can be set by the employer), a dialog is displayed that offers a warning something along the lines of "Your cover letter is quite long. Are you sure you want to submit it?".

This way employers expecting detailed cover letters can still receive them, and employers who appreciate succinctness have a better chance of getting it.