# Candidates on Careers coming from contract houses without the site telling me that

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

We have had a job listing for quite some time on Stack Overflow Careers.  Most recently we had received 3 applications, and [although the résumés were very long](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320298/what-can-be-done-to-remind-candidates-to-slim-down-their-resumes), I decided to pursue contacting them to understand more about them - give them the benefit of the doubt instead of judging them.

I called the first candidate and got some other guy, when I asked him who he was he said he was the actual boss of the candidate I was looking for.  Odd: I thought I was calling the number listed on the résumé, and it ends up being the boss of the candidate.  I then mentioned to this candidate's boss that I must have the wrong number, and hung up.

So I decided to call my next candidate...got on the phone and another guy gets on.  I said are you so and so, they said no, I am the boss of so and so.  I again thought this was odd.  I said I must have the wrong number...and again hung up.

Two minutes later my phone rings.  This time it is the second candidate.  I explained to her that I used the number she had provided on her résumé.  She laughed and said "yes, that is my employer".  I told her to rewind for a second and think about it: why would you do that to me?  She said she was a contractor working for that company and that company was looking for contract positions.

This is nuts. I wasted a few hours with contract companies, trying to fill roles for their candidates.  Nowhere on SO Careers/Jobs was it telling me this is some sort of contract role.  My job listing specifically mentioned that we are looking to bring on direct full time hires, not contractors.

Why oh why isn't this stuff filtered or checked before?  I'm angry because I've been fooled, not once, but twice, and actually maybe three times.  I'm scared to even contact this next candidate.

Later, I called the third candidate only to get this same sort of scenario, and on top of that, the candidate mentioned this employer wrote their résumé for them.  Sorry, SO Careers, the candidates we get are all crap.  All three were a bust. I cannot believe it.  Contract houses trying to get on the map, writing the resumes for people they want to "sell" to us.  I dislike it in every sense.  It feels like a scam.

Comment: Ending up with some contractor approaching you happens occasionally when you try to recruit people through all kinds of media. Why not simply tell the "boss": - thank you for letting me know where to head-hunt a person matching the profile I'm trying to recruit, I'll now shamelessly poach them from your company and offer them new full-time employment.

Answer (score 15):

This is a problem that can't be easily solved. The only way for us to 100% fix this issue would be to screen every single person that applies before sending the candidate on to you. Unfortunately that requires a huge amount of work that would be untenable for us in terms of man power.

If you have candidates that you feel applied to your posting in a misleading manner, please let us know at careers@stackoverflow.com and we will review it and potentially ban them (we've banned tons of recruiters and contract companies because of this). If they applied with an official Stack Overflow CV, there is an option on the page to flag them as well.

Comment: How about requiring a unique StackOverflow account for each application? That should make it much harder for a recruiter to mass submit lots of resumes.