# Flagging user on careers does nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Because of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320934/careers-candidates-coming-from-contract-houses-but-no-where-does-it-tell-me-th) I decided to flag some users.  When I click "flag user" and select "other" and then submit, nothing happens...

[image: flag this user]

There is no message or confirmation that the user has been flagged.

What is happening here, and how do I really flag this user?

Comment: When the candidate experience got moved over to stackoverflow.com/jobs, somehow flagging candidates got moved as well. I'll get it working shortly.

Comment: @SteveTrout - Just in case you miss my comment from the other post flagging the user should automatically dismiss the candidate as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Saw that other comment. I'll check if that happens. FYI your browser is blocking the request after the redirect, so you'll have to reflag those users once it's fixed.

Comment: @SteveTrout - Once you're good on your end let me know and I'll clear my cache and restart this entire process.

Comment: @SteveTrout - I tried it again with no luck.  The error is pretty bare bones.  Something went wrong it says...

Answer (score 4):

Flagging users should work again now. Those flags didn't go through, so you'll have to submit again. Sorry about that. TL;DR we moved the flagging feature in a way that made it break.

Technical explanation: We moved the candidate-facing parts of Careers to stackoverflow.com/jobs. In doing this, almost all of the /cv routes were moved, so we just listed the exceptions and redirected everything not on that list. /cv/flag -- where flag requests are sent -- should have been an exception but we missed it.

When your browser sees a JavaScript request to stackoverflow.com from a page on careers.stackoverflow.com, it blocks it unless it's specifically told it's OK. The UI doesn't handle the failure case well, either, as you noticed [in your other bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320941/following-up-a-flag-to-flag-another-user-on-careers-is-met-with-another-dead-end).

Comment: So this should in fact fix both cases as this case caused the other bug report correct?

Comment: this still does not work...The error message I get is "something went wrong".

Comment: Strange, your requests are missing an anti-forgery form value (a hidden field named "fkey") so they're being ignored as spam. Have you refreshed the page? Do you have any extensions active in your browser?

Comment: went as far as clearing all my cache / history (which I hate to do) and clicked on it just now as well...same issue.

Comment: Tested this in both IE and Chrome (latest versions) with same issue.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me here. I'm still digging. The flags are definitely not being created but there's no error showing up in our logs.

Comment: No problem I can run some more tests using firefox / opera.

Comment: upon inspection the jquery post is setting an fkey for me.  Do you need the form data?

Comment: The fkey field is fine now, actually (just the one request had it missing). The "something went wrong" you're seeing is because the candidate you're flagging doesn't have an account. We don't have an appropriate error message for that case so you see a generic one.

Comment: We should add something to handle reporting of spam applicants without accounts as well, of course. I'll pass that along.

Comment: ok so you do see the fkey, that's a good start.  I have a candidate id without a cvid which i assume is okay as the candidate hasn't built a cv it appears on stackoverflow.  So this is something else then?

Comment: Flagging only does something if the user has a CV. It should probably notify us regardless, but the form is working as designed currently (just without a good message explaining why the flag wasn't successful).

Comment: So I'm confused, does that mean my flag went through correctly or not?  Also if it did go through correctly, don't you think the logical thing to do would be either "Dismiss" the candidate so I don't see them or simply HARD delete them from my list of candidates?

Comment: Ugh upon reading your comment it sounds to me nothing was done nor is it intended to do it.  So you are saying the flag user link is pointless if the user has no cvId ?  Which to me means you should set that link `display: none;` if there is no cv...otherwise again you are misleading the end user into thinking this is actually doing something.  Case in point, how in the world do I flag this candidate or any candidate for that matter?

Comment: Flagging candidates who have CVs now works, and is intended to work. (That's what I fixed today). Flagging candidates with no CV doesn't work (as @Juice mentioned in your other question, you should email us in those cases). It might be best to hide the link in that case. As an immediate fix I'll add a suggestion to email support about the candidate to the "something went wrong" message.

Comment: You have to admit this is a very broken process.  I'm in the flow of looking at candidates and I get to the point I need to flag one.  I cannot anymore (due to some internal details like not having a CV) so I stop and then I email (outside of the app) careers@stackoverflow.com to fix something that should of been handled on the UI?  I mean don't you agree thats rather odd?  Why is the CV needed, and if it is needed why can you not just put an option or a different link appears for people who dont have a CV.  Sorry I'm not going out of my workflow to fix this..there has to be a .

Comment: ...a better way to address this.  The error messages don't make sense, the internal details of what is needed vs not needed don't make sense.  The UX is confusing because I am presented with links that really I should not click on because of details that I should remember.  None of this makes any sense and any sane person performing this operation is going to hate it.

Comment: Sorry I refuse to accept this as an answer - this is a broken process and it needs clarification and a better workflow.  Can someone from the team address if this entire workflow is going to change?  I mean unless the CEO of this company @spolsky comes on here and says you know what JonH I agree with Steve Trout this is the way we are going to roll, I simply won't have other customers deal with this.  I was happy to be the guinea pig and test this but to put this out to paying customers is simply wrong.  It wasted my time and I don't want it to waste anyone elses.

Comment: @SteveTrout The link says "Flag this user". Not "flag this CV". Why should the employer have to care if they have a CV or not? And hiding the link is not appropriate - just because they don't have a CV doesn't mean they shouldn't be flaggable. The clear way forward here is to make flagging work regardless of whether the user has a CV or not.

Comment: @JonH You're right; this was implemented poorly. Flags were intended as a way for us to be able to identify and block bad profiles from appearing in the candidate search database, but there are some cases where applications (from users with and without SO/Careers profiles) and profiles for candidates saved from search are presented the same way. The fact that flags don't work for users who applied anonymously was an oversight, which I apologize for; we're talking internally about how this *should* work, but I need to get in touch with the person who originally implemented this first.

Comment: We won't leave it like this, though; you're right that this is a broken process. We will either make flagging work as expected for all candidates, or we'll remove the link from applicants that don't have a CV.