# Following up a flag to flag another user on careers is met with another dead end

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

After posting [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320934/candidates-on-careers-coming-from-contract-houses-without-the-site-telling-me-th) I decided to take the advice of Juice and flag the candidate.  I did and ended up posting [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320938/flagging-user-on-careers-does-nothing).  Great so he mentions they still got pinged even though I did not get a confirmation.  Fine I thought I'd go flag my next user...

Here's where the problem is...after you flag one user the Submit button stays disabled...

[image]

You can no longer flag any other user.  Steps to reproduce:

1. Flag first user
2. Go to another candidate on careers you want to flag
3. Flag this user
4. Try to click Submit button

Comment: @Steve Trout - Flagging a user should also "Dismiss" them automatically if that isn't the case already.

Comment: The UI isn't handling a failing request gracefully. When the other bug is fixed this one won't surface -- I'll make sure it handles backend failures better after I get the other problem taken care of.

Comment: @SteveTrout Thanks let me know when this is complete so I can complete these.

Comment: @SteveTrout - This is now throwing an error message that says "Something went wrong".

Comment: @SteveTrout Based on your other post, the submit button still doesnt work, Im just trying to get the jquery form post values to send in the email (this has the candidate id).  But once I get it for one candidate it doesnt work for another.  I have to hard refresh to get it to become active.  This is a bug.

Comment: Right you are, that's still a bug. I'll get it fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed. The problem was occurring because we weren't resetting the UI state when you navigated to the next user.